# Toggle switch component in vue reactivity issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have this toggle component, that if it's toggled it will do some query to the DB and only if the query is success the toggle state will be changed. Like this:

[sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

But the issue is, if im using @change it will change the toggle state even the query is failed. So im using @click.prevent instead so the checkbox doesnt automatically being checked. The problem is if i click the toggle, the props is changing but not with the toggle. And funny part if i change the toggleState via vue devtools, the toggle changes.

---

TLDR: I want the toggle be toggled or untoggled only if the query resolves, if the query fails I don't want the toggle to be changed.

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: I want the toggle to be toggled or untoggled only if the query is resolved. If the query fails, i dont want the toggle to be changed.

Comment: It also changes if you remove the `.prevent`. Vue devtools are mainly overriding the state here. As for the rest of the question, you could have an "optimistic response", meaning that if you toggle your thing and expect it to be set by default to `true` because it is likely to be, you can do that. Otherwise, you should probably add something different like a button + loader to let the user know that your query is pending, then print the result once you have the response from the backend. A toggle _could_ also be fine but still, some UX will be needed to provide feedback to the user.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but I would do is use a @change event where I disable the toggle as soon as it has changed, and reenable it once the query completes.

Comment: Yeah if i remove the prevent, the toggle will automatically changes even if the query fails. Which not what i wanted.

Comment: If you still want to stick to your toggle, you can indeed disable the component and then, depending of the answer toggle it or not. I recommend not setting it to `true` until you get the answer tho. Meaning, that it's better to let "false - wait - true" than "false - true - wait - rollback to false" UX wise. I understood that, just explained why the devtools are still having an impact since you mentioned it.

Comment: @kissu yeah the problem is even in the example im giving its not even a wait for query yet, its just simple to  negate the toggle status but the toggle still didnt change.

Comment: I recommend using a button, making it work for a simple boolean. Then switch into adapting it to a toggle. Don't do too much things at the same time: you'll solve it faster.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.